# Tag synonym for "XMPP": "Jabber"

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [xmpp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/xmpp) and a [jabber](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jabber) tag.

Current stats:

- tagged with xmpp: [77 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/xmpp)
- tagged with jabber: [52 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jabber)
- tagged with both: [25 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jabber+xmpp)

As far as I can see, they are used for the same thing: *XMPP*, formerly known as *Jabber*. (Note that *JABBER®* is [now a registered trademark](https://superuser.com/a/460796/151741), and isn’t necessarily related to XMPP anymore.)

I propose to add [jabber](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jabber) as synonym for [xmpp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/xmpp).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty telling that half the questions in [jabber](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/jabber) also had [xmpp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/xmpp) already.

Merged and synonymized.